# Magento 1.9 - After indexing, update at time doesn't change on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, index

As website is bigger, I can see some issues on index process.
After indexing, update at time of `product prices` doesn't change on Magento

[image]

Comparing to time of indexing, index of `product prices` takes 2 mins

[image]

Is it a megento bug? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) The `var/locks` directory is created whenever you start an indexing process. Magento writes out a lock file to this directory so removing the lock files may resolve issues with reindexing.

Locate `var/locks` directory and remove all files under this directory. This will clear all the locks for **re-indexing** to take place again.

if the directory isn't there! Magento hasn't created it. If this is the case, then you should look for other solutions for fixing the reindexing issue.

Maybe your var directory doesn't have the right **permissions**. Magento needs sufficient permissions to be able to create the `var/locks` directory and write out the lock files. Try setting permissions for var to (at least) **755**.

2) Try to reindex via SSH.

Indexing ALL:

`php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Indexing individually:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
php shell/indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```

3) If All this doesn't work try this: go to your **database** and **truncate** `core_url_rewrite`, then **reindex** directly either with the **ssh** preferably like this `php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall` or via the admin.

4) Clear Magento and navigator **cache**.